# Confusion with degrees of freedom, some say CO2 has 9, others say 6

Tags: energy

My textbook doesn't consider vibration modes when determining the degree of freedom. Some other sources I have found don't either. But wikipedia, other sources, and even other users here apparently use the vibrational part to determine the degree of freedom. What is going on here? Can someone explain why it is so different?

Comment: If you have other information to add to the question it's usually a better idea to edit the previous one instead of posting a new one.

Comment: Are you referring to the "possible duplicate" or is there a question of mine that is very similar to this one

Comment: Also my questions are different because the other one wanted to know why CO2 had a degree of 6 when I thought one of the possible rotational axis was actually not a degree of rotation

Comment: $\ce{CO2}$ has 4 degrees of freedom for vibrations - the rule is $3N - 5$ for a linear molecule.  There are 3 translational and 2 rotational degrees of freedom - the other 4 are vibrational, of which 2 are degenerate. See [this](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Core/Physical_Chemistry/Spectroscopy/Vibrational_Spectroscopy/Vibrational_Modes/Normal_Modes) page for a more complete explanation.